# Elastic NEST Update single document

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Im trying to track down some documentation for updating a single document using NEST.
I can get a specific document using GET

```
elasticClient.Get<Product>(ProductId);
```

And would assume it would be something along the same lines for updating but not sure.

Comment: I wrote a blog post some time ago that covers `GET -> MODIFY -> INDEX` and `UPDATE`, albeit within the context of optimistic concurrency control: https://forloop.co.uk/blog/optimistic-concurrency-with-elasticsearch-and-nest. The information is still relevant, although some syntax has slightly changed in NEST since 1.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch Nest Insert/Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025484/elasticsearch-nest-insert-update)