# How Insert or Update document in ElasticSearch NEST 6

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How to Insert or Update document in ElasticSearch NEST 6

I want to store web page view event per user to elastic index. if ViewEvent for the specific user exists then Insert, else plus 1 count of existing ViewEvent.

The elastic document type is Post

```
public class ViewEvent
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

I can do this by following the REST request:

```
http://192.168.20.80:9200/db/ViewEvent/2/_update

{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "ctx._source.count += 1;"
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "userId": 2,
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Problem is when I try to do this by NEST client. Update part through the following code done.

```
var response1 = await _vastContext.Client(indexName)
    .UpdateByQueryAsync<VastEvent>(u => u.Query(query => 
                query.Terms(term => term.Field(f => f.UserId).Terms(2)))
    .Script(script => script.Source($"ctx._source.count += 1;")
            .Lang(ScriptLang.Painless)));
```

**I cannot add upsert part to the request!**

Comment: I believe this post can come in handy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025484/elasticsearch-nest-insert-update

Comment: You're using `.UpdateByQuery(...)`. You should use `.Update(...)` instead

Comment: @Green, I need script part but the post that you mentioned not have script part

Comment: @Russ Cam, by Update how add query part